# App update submit - Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK, Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm upgrading my app and when I try to submit I get the message "This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK, Xcode"

[image]

This is a screenshot from my app. If you need more data about my system or app configuration, just let me know.

Thanks

UPDATE

XCode version: 4.2 - Build 4D177b

Comment: Seems you have installed an invalid SDK for application submission (either to old or beta). Which XCode Version do you have installed?

Comment: XCode 4.2 - Build 4D177b

Comment: You will have to upgrade your XCode installation. The current release versions are 4D502 (Lion) and 4C199 (Snow Leopard). Also the "b" at your XCode version indicates that you are using still a beta release which are generally not accepted for app submission.

Comment: I was confused because App Store says that I have the latest version installed and I just can't find the download link that is not related to App Store. I'll dig a little more, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok to turn my comment into an Answer:

You will have to upgrade your XCode installation. The current release versions are 4D502 (Lion) and 4C199 (Snow Leopard). Also the "b" at your XCode version indicates that you are using still a beta release which are generally not accepted for app submission.

If the AppStore insist that you have the latest version go to your "Applications" folder
and **delete** the "*XCode Installer.app*". Then you can download it again from the AppStore.

It probably would also do no harm if you'd removed your installation entirely, therefore go to a terminal and navigate to your XCode directory (usually /Developer) and enter

```
sudo Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Then download a fresh installer from the AppStore and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The screen shot has nothing to do with the error.
The problem should be with your xCode version and the SDK it uses.
Upgrade your xCode and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Apple probably wants your app to be up to date, which means the IDE Xcode also needs to be up to date. Sometimes to update, unfortunately, you might have to download the entire .dmg file from Apple's website again.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem could be your base installation if you have upgraded from 10.6. Check and see with `sudo sysctl kern.osversion` if you see a trailing letter your system thinks it is a beta verion as in `kern.osversion: 11D50b`. You can change it with `sudo sysctl -w kern.osversion=11D50` but will have to do so after each boot.
`